# How to keep Hibernate from requiring the use of a primary key

Tags: java, hibernate, primary-key

In my table, I have an ID/column that acts as a Primary Key. At the database level, the key is generated by a sequence function. For example, in Oracle, it is something like:

```
CREATE SEQUENCE SEQ_CUSTOMER
        INCREMENT BY 1
        START WITH 5
        MAXVALUE 999999999999
        MINVALUE 5
        ORDER;
```

In MySQL, I believe there is a way to specify an ID/Primary Key so that a value is generated for it (automatically) on insert.

In my case, I have used Hibernate to generate the Java code (based on the DB Table Definition). The problem is that whenever creating a record, Hibernate wants a value to be assigned a value to the Primary Key. It looks like:

```
@Id
@Column(name = "CUSTOMERID", unique = true, nullable = false, precision = 22, scale = 0)
public BigDecimal getCustomerid() {
    return this.customerid;
}
```

How can I specify (or annotate) the ID so that it will not require a value to be assigned and just allow the key to be generated at the DB level?

TIA

Comment: `@GeneratedValue(GenerationType.AUTO)` should work. [more information here](https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/jpa/2.1/api/javax/persistence/GeneratedValue.html)

Comment: More readable explanation of `@GeneratedValue` [here](http://www.objectdb.com/java/jpa/entity/generated)

Comment: Thanks @XtremeBaumer will try it out

Comment: Thanks @Robin Topper  will follow up!